# Should "from" always be paired with "to" in descriptions of time ranges?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, range-inclusion

Back in school I was taught that "from" should always be paired with "to" to indicate time ranges, as in

> Queen Victoria reigned from 1837 to 1901.

But now, I frequently see a dash used instead of "to," following "from":

> Queen Victoria reigned from 1837-1901.

Is that combination of word and dash correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Have you done any research? That way, our community can better help you answer your question.

Comment: Thank you and yes, I did. “from 2009–2012” and “between 2009–2012” are incorrect; either use both from and to, or between and and, or neither" , This gives me an impression people are illiterate, even newspaper editors...

Comment: Can you share that research with us? It helps us not to duplicate efforts.

Comment: Now I found an answer to my own question. Thank you

Comment: Great! Can you put it in an answer and accept it? So if other people have the same question as you did, they can find it here :)

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily a style question, although there is a strong consensus among style guides that mixing opening range words (*from* or *between*) with punctuation marks (a hyphen [-] or an en dash [–]) instead of with closing range words (*to* or *and*) is bad form.

*Words Into Type*, third edition (1974), for example, offers a detailed guideline on this point:

> To represent *to* between figures or words an en dash is used. (Some publisher accept a hyphen but those who use the en dash feel that a hyphen is a poor substitute and should be reserved for its own uses, as a connector in compound words and as a separator in showing syllabication.)
>
> > [Example:] the years 1970–73
>
> The word *to*, not an en dash, must be used if the numbers are preceded by the word *from*.
>
> > *Wrong:* Completion of the transcontinental railroad from 1869–1885.
> >
> > *Right:* Completion of the transcontinental railroad from 1869 to 1885.
> >
> > *Or:* Completion of the transcontinental railroad, 1869–1885.

To similar effect is the advice in the *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **9.62** *When to use the en dash.* An en dash used between two numbers implies *up to and including*, or *through*
>
> > [Relevant example:] Here are the figures for 1999–2000
>
> **9.63** *When not to use the en dash.* If *from* or *between* is used before the first of a pair of numbers, the en dash should not be used; instead, *from* should be followed by *to* or *through*, *between* by *and*. The wording should indicate the degree of inclusiveness. Avoid *between ... and* where precision is required.

Other style guides may differ on this point, of course, but the general argument in favor of consistency seems well expressed here by both WIT and Chicago.

Answer (score 0):

Either use both *from* and *to*, or *between* and *and*, or neither.

Comment: During the time frame 1990-1995 ...